Cannot get cuda toolkit or nvidia drivers on my dual booted ubunutu 22.04 machine
Recently got into reinforcement learning, been solving lots of openAI-GYM environments .
while doing this , im struggling with training time for my models , so i wish to utilize the nvidia-gpu that i have on my laptop .
but getting cuda toolkit, cudnn and nvidia drivers on my machine has been a big-big problem .
i have dual booted ubuntu 22.04 for programming purposes on my windows laptop .
send any guides or general tips that have worked for you .

Can you add a bit more info about your system? What GPU do you have?
Also, I recommend installing any Python-based environment using Anaconda or Miniconda, to keep packages messing up with the ones native to Ubuntu.

Usually you only need to install CUDA before hand ( see this guide ) and then you can use to install the OpenAI gym on conda.
Most likely you will need to install beforehand the corresponding CUDA Toolkit version, which is usually installed by Anaconda when you install a DL framework such as Pytorch via conda install pytorch torchvision pytorch-cuda=XX.X -c pytorch -c nvidia
